# What is the proper syntax for SQL?

Tags: abap, opensql

I'm trying to create a SQL statement in ABAP that selects multiple fields but can't figure out the proper syntax for it.

This was what I was doing that generated an error:

```
SELECT field1, field2
  FROM table INTO txtbox
  WHERE field3 = txtInput. 
ENDSELECT.
```

All fields are in the same table.

Comment: Please provide the error message and the complete code (i. e. variable declarations, table structure definition)

Comment: It dependes on the ABAP version as well. What ABAP version do you have?

Comment: press f1 on the "select" in the editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Syntax may depend on the version of the ABAP.**

Your problem probably due to the erroneous declaration / selection of variables to query.

Some examples:

```
*Select all fields of a SAP database table into in internal table
SELECT *
  FROM ekko
  INTO TABLE it_ekko.


*Select directly into an internal table
SELECT bukrs belnr gjahr buzei mwskz umsks prctr hkont xauto koart
       dmbtr mwart hwbas aufnr projk shkzg kokrs
  FROM bseg
  INTO TABLE it_bseg.


* Select directly into an internal table where fields are in a
* different order or not all fields are specified 
SELECT bukrs belnr gjahr buzei mwskz umsks prctr hkont xauto koart
       dmbtr mwart hwbas aufnr projk shkzg kokrs
  FROM bseg
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE it_bseg.


*Select... endselect command (to structure)
SELECT bukrs belnr gjahr buzei mwskz umsks prctr hkont xauto koart
       dmbtr mwart hwbas aufnr projk shkzg kokrs
  FROM bseg
  INTO wa_bseg.

  APPEND wa_bseg TO it_bseg.
ENDSELECT.


*Select FOR ALL ENTRIES command
SELECT bukrs belnr gjahr bldat monat budat xblnr awtyp awkey
  UP TO 100 ROWS
  FROM bkpf
  INTO TABLE it_bkpf.

IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
* The FOR ALL ENTRIES comand only retrieves data which matches
* entries within a particular internal table.
  SELECT bukrs belnr gjahr buzei mwskz umsks prctr hkont xauto koart
         dmbtr mwart hwbas aufnr projk shkzg kokrs
    FROM bseg
    INTO TABLE it_bseg
    FOR ALL ENTRIES IN it_bkpf
    WHERE bukrs EQ it_bkpf-bukrs AND
          belnr EQ it_bkpf-belnr AND
          gjahr EQ it_bkpf-gjahr.
ENDIF.
```

Comment: Unfortunately not entirely true. In the new OpenSQL the fields can (and should) be separated by commas. More info [here](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/index.htm?file=abenopensql_strict_modes.htm).

Comment: @Jagger: Thanks for information, I edited my answer. 
I was not aware of the changes in the new version abap.

Answer (score 2):

At first, you are trying to select 2 fields into 1 variable. Is it what you are trying to achieve? Is txtbox a structure?

At second, syntax related - depending on ABAP version youshould write either

```
SELECT field1, field2
  FROM table INTO @txtbox
  WHERE field3 = @txtInput. 
ENDSELECT.
```

Or

```
SELECT field1 field2
  FROM table INTO txtbox
  WHERE field3 = txtInput. 
ENDSELECT.
```